# Knowing when scrollToRowAtIndexPath doesn't scroll

Tags: uitableview, animation

After adding a row to a table, I'm using **scrollToRowAtIndexPath** to position the row in the middle of the screen, then relying on **scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation** to highlight the same row.

Sometimes, the row can't be scrolled; e.g., when it's one of the first in the table. In these cases, **scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation** isn't called so the newly added row isn't highlighted.

Is there a way to know whether or not **scrollToRowAtIndexPath** will have any effect on the table?

Comment: Are you inserting only one row at a time?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

While inserting you would have to specify indexPaths to be inserted right?
Store these indexPaths publically and reload that row with highligted color in CellForRowAtIndexPath or reload the rows individually.

Eg:
Add the indexpaths of inserted row to the public array.

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexpathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

self.colorIndexs = indexpathArray;
```

Then add this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if ([colorIndexs count] > 0 && [colorIndexs containsObject:indexPath])

customCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Potentially my explanation wasn't clear: by highlight, I meant that I'm using animateWithDuration to setHighlighted:YES followed by setHighlighted:NO on animation completion for the inserted cell. So, in effect, the cell's background highlights, the goes back to normal after it has scrolled to the center of the view. It looks like you're solution would permanently change the background colour of inserted cells.

Comment: ok.. then instead of changing the color in above code, just write your `setHighlighted:NO` and YES in the above code. wont that solve the purpose?

Comment: No: your solution would execute setHighlighted on view load which is fine when the table view doesn't need to scroll to bring the cell into view. When it does need to scroll, the setHighlighted animation will likely occur while the cell is off screen. So the scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation works for the latter case and your solution works when scrolling isn't required; I just need a solution that handles both. Thanks for trying.